# C# DataContract force PascalCase output

Tags: c#, datacontractjsonserializer

The DataContract likes to accept the input properties in PascalCase (as the property names are in PascalCase as well in C#) unless I manually set the property name to camelCase (using JsonProperty). But doesn't the same doesn't let me output in PascalCase (as I would like to maintain consistency in my input and output serialization).

In short, how can I ensure the output of my datacontract serialization is in PascalCase and not camelCase (the latter is the default for me).

I have tried using [DataMember(Name = "camelCaseName")] and also [JsonProperty("camelCaseName")] but none of them work (although the latter works to take input into the data contract in camelCase, but not the output).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Its not clear what's the issue you are facing. Are you doing Json Serialization? Do you want json to be create with property names with `PascalCase` or`camelCase`? You need to use Json property attribute properly. For example for property with name `FirstName` you should use `JsonProperty["firstName"]` for camelCase and `JsonProperty["FirstName"]` for PascalCase

Comment: *I have tried using [DataMember(Name = "camelCaseName")] and also [JsonProperty("camelCaseName")] but none of them work* - then might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?